# No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.Transform.RotateAround' for the argument list

Tags: unity, unityscript

Assets/CircularOrbit.js(11,26): BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.Transform.RotateAround' for the argument list '(UnityEngine.Vector3, System.Type, float)' was found.

Here is what I what I did:

```
   var mountain : GameObject;
// This will return the game object named Hand in the scene.
   mountain = GameObject.Find("QuantumCold_B");
   transform.RotateAround(mountain.transform.position, Vector2,20 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Where mountain is mesh in the scene Perhaps its not really game object with a position? or position is not a Vector3?

Comment: -1 This is a basic programming question. And not game dev specific. You may be making a game, but the error you're getting is not game dev related. Practice basic debugging skills, read your error messages and try to understand what they're saying. Use the scripting documentation I gave you in your previous question to ensure you're using the Unity function calls correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the 2nd parameter, `Vector2`, with `Vector3.Up`

Comment: I did replace and that fixed the problem.  My first person object however is falling with respect to the mountain rather than circling it. Do you know how I can keep the first person object level while it RotatesAround mountain mesh?

Comment: @gitright Comments aren't the place for further questions. Comments are used for clarification and suggesting improvements. Please ask a new question if you have one. Make sure to do a bit of research first.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59610/how-to-keep-gameobject-first-person-from-dropping-while-rotating-around-an-objec

Answer (score 0):

The [`RotateAround` function](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) takes three parameters: a `Vector3` for the point, a `Vector3` for the axis, and a `float` representing the angle.

You are passing a position (a `Vector3`), the name of a type (an instance of `System.Type`), and the angle (a `float`). One of these things is not like the other: you are passing an incompatible value for the second parameter to the function.

Presumably you meant to pass an actual `Vector3` representing the rotation axis.

Comment: Ok. I now pass in  transform.RotateAround(mountain.transform.position, Vector3.up,20 * Time.deltaTime); and at least this compiles.  I removed gravity from Character Motor, but the first person object seems to continue to fall with respect to the mountain. Is there something wrong with Vector3.up?

Comment: I have added the follow up question here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59610/how-to-keep-gameobject-first-person-from-dropping-while-rotating-around-an-objec