# How to keep a GameObject from dropping?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I am applying the following script to first person object:

```
function Update () {
   var mountain : GameObject;

   mountain = GameObject.Find("QuantumCold_B");
   transform.RotateAround(mountain.transform.position, Vector3.up,20 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

When I run this it looks like the mountain is turning and the first person object is falling. I applied this script to the first person object thinking it would rotate around the mountain.  Perhaps I need to apply lookAt in some way?  How do I keep the first person object form falling?

I did set the gravity=0 for motor section of Character Motor Script.

Comment: What have you tried? I'm assume you've tried disabling gravity on the first person object for example?

Comment: well i set gravity to zero in Character Motor Script Section.  Not sure if this was right place though.

Comment: Does the Character Motor Script game object have a RigidBody component?

Comment: More dismaying to me is that the mountain itself seems to spin/rotate in front of the first person object. Rather than the FPO circling the mountain. Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: No I don't see a RigidBody component attached.

Comment: Well, if the gameobject that contains the Character Motor Script is falling, something is applying gravity to it. Without more information, we'd just be guessing about what that might be. For this question, please provide more information about what's happening in your scene and what other components are attached to the game object holding your script. The issue with the mountain spinning should be addressed in [your other question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59585/how-to-circle-an-uneven-object-with-camera-at-a-fixed-distance?rq=1)

Comment: I updated that question with more information. I have not explicitly added a rigid body to anything. Just added first person object, and mesh.

Comment: I updated the question ....

Comment: You shouldn't do GameObject.Find every frame, that searches every object in the scene by name.  Instead prefer to save off the result in a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

You keep a game object from dropping by removing or disabling any scripts that might be altering its position.